# Least amount of code to stop a link from firing (on all browsers)

Tags: javascript

When I want a function to stop a link and continue on executing my own code, I do this:

```
        // IE
        if (e.cancelBubble) {
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }

        // Firefox
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        // Others
        if (e.defaultPrevented) {
            e.defaultPrevented();
        }

        alert('still executing my function');
```

Is all that really necessary, or could I do it with less code?

Comment: None of those will stop a link (an `<a>` tag) from "firing" when clicked.

Comment: Are you glazing over your browser check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply make the function `return false` for javascript.

Since you mentioned in your comment you are using a jQuery click method, add the `event.preventDefault()`.

```
$('#mylink').click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    //code here
})
```

[jquery Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.x-master/src/event.js#L718%20jQuery%20source) (thanks to BenjaminGreunbaum) for pointing out that jQuery normalizes events, thus `event.returnValue` is already handled.

For javascript, you'll want to add an `eventListener`.

```
function derp(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById("mylink").addEventListener('click', derp, false);
```

Comment: I clarified my question to specify that I want to continue executing after preventing the link event.

Comment: You mean you want a block of code to execute, or you want to submit the link after something?

Comment: On $('#mylink').click(function() { }) I want to prevent loading the href and execute my own block of code.

Comment: How was this accepted? This does not work in IE. See my answer for a working solution.

Comment: @khellang jQuery which OP uses (from the comment) normalizes this for you. Also, preventDefault works in all modern browsers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return false` as it is effectively the same as calling both `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation`

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occurring, `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and `return false` will do both.

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple `return false;` statement.

This will work in all browsers.

Comment: I wont downvote, but honestly, I posted the exact same answer 2 minutes before this. You should read the answers before posting to avoid duplicates.

Comment: -1 What advantage does this answer offer over @RUJordan's from 3 minutes ago?

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya Benefit of the doubt and all, but it took you 3 minutes to type "Write a simple return false; statement." :)?